# Get a count of values selected in a multi-select picklist on all contacts

Tags: lightning, custom-object, contact, multi-select

I have a multi-select picklist (colors__c) in my contact object (with 20 records). Let us say the picklist has 4 values (red, blue, green, yellow). And I have a separate object (object__c), which contains a field named "Count" (count__c). Here I want to display the total number of colors selected. For example, if 10 contacts selected red, 15 selected blue, 11 selected green and 6 selected yellow, then I want result to be something like this:

| Color | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 10 |
| Blue | 15 |
| Green | 11 |
| Yellow | 6 |

How can I achieve this? Also what should be the data-type of Count.

Comment: It seems that you cannot run a straight `count` based on the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions_field_types.htm). To get more help can you tell what have you tried so far and where have you got stuck?

Comment: @JefersonChaves Actually I am a beginner. So all my attempts were pretty basic. Like trying to use trigger, trying rollup, etc. But to no use. 
So if you could help me from the start it would be good. Thanks.